# Unable to find child element from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` and trying to find (using FindResource) of `DoubleAnimation` element in code behind.
Examp:-

```
<UserControl ....
   <Canvas Width="400" Height="400" Loaded="Canvas_Loaded">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="sd" x:Name="sBoard ">
            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="SomeAnimation" ...
```

I am trying to find “SomeAnimation” in `Canvas_Loaded` method.

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to activate the animation from code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method expect a resource key which `SomeAnimation` doesn't have.
You can use it to find the `Storyboard` resource with using the `sd` key and find your animation from there.

```
private void Canvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var canvas = sender as Canvas;

    var storyboard = canvas.FindResource("sd") as Storyboard;
    var someAnimation = storyboard.Children.First() as DoubleAnimation;
}
```

If you do that in order to activate the animation you can do it using [BeginStoryboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598109.aspx) method

```
var storyboard = canvas.FindResource("sd") as Storyboard;
canvas.BeginStoryboard(storyboard);
```

or simply

```
storyboard.Begin();
```

Hope this helps